# javafx combobox contextmenu not displayed

Tags: combobox, javafx, contextmenu

my problem is:
i made a combobox and i want to use context menu on it's elements, so when i'm setting the cellfactory as shown below, i can't see the items in any more and the context menu does not show.

```
CBXGroups.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, ListCell<String>>() {
    public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> param) {
    final ListCell<String> cell = new ListCell<String>();
    final ContextMenu cellMenu = new ContextMenu();
    MenuItem rimuoviDalControllo = new MenuItem("RIMUOVI DAL CONTROLLO");
    MenuItem rimuoviDefinitivamente = new MenuItem("RIMUOVI DEFINITIVAMENTE");
    rimuoviDalControllo.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        Service.deleteGroupFromControl(cell.getText(),CBXControllo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        populateLists();
        }
    });
    rimuoviDefinitivamente.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        Service.deleteGroup(cell.getText());
        populateLists();
        }
    });
    cellMenu.setOnShowing(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
        public void handle(WindowEvent event) {
        cell.requestFocus();
        }
    });
    cellMenu.getItems().addAll(rimuoviDalControllo,rimuoviDefinitivamente);
    cell.contextMenuProperty().bind(Bindings.when(Bindings.isNotNull(cell.itemProperty())).then(cellMenu).otherwise((ContextMenu) null));
    return cell;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't see the items because you haven't set the text in your `ListCell`. You can do this with a one-liner:

```
cell.textProperty().bind(cell.itemProperty());
```

The context menu is trickier, and I don't really have a solution for it. The issue is that the `ComboBox` uses a [`PopupControl`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/PopupControl.html) to display the list view, and the popup control has `autoHide` set to true. So when you click on the list view, the popup closes (preventing you seeing the context menu). There's no way to access the popup control, so I don't think there's going to be any way to do this.

Registering a context menu with items in a combo box seems like an unusual thing to do; I wonder if there is a better approach for what you want to do. A [`MenuButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuButton.html) is similar to a `ComboBox` in some ways (control that displays a popup with options), but it has a menu hierarchy so you can include cascading menus. This might provide the kind of functionality you want.